# Get data from an API using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, api

I'm trying for learning purposes to get data from an open API for quizzes.

What I started is to get the data from API and in `console.log()` see if I'm doing right.
I'm parsing the URL before the `foreach`but I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
```

This is the sample code I'm trying and I understood that I have to parse the JSON first before the foreach but is not working for me and cannot see why

```
/**
 *
 * @GET url of the API https://opentdb.com
 *
 */
// Creating a request variable with the OBJ inside
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Opening a GET request to the API
request.open("GET", "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10");
// Load the request
request.onload = function() {
    // Accessing the JSON data
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    // Checking if we have status 200 good to go otherwise error
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        // Looping the data
        data.forEach(results => {
            console.log(results.question);
        });
    } else {
        // Showing error for the status
        console.log("error");
    }
};
// Request send
request.send();
```

EDIT Showing the asked data content from `console.log(data)`

[image: Result of console.log()]

Comment: What happens if you `console.log` out `data`?

Comment: maybe your data is not array or it's getting null

Comment: I edit adding the screenshot of the `console.log(data)`

Comment: For future reference: Your error message gives you a big clue. data.forEach is not a function. forEach is a function only on arrays, so that means your data object is not an array, so you should look to see what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are accessing whole response, instead get results `this.response.results`:

```
var data = JSON.parse(this.response).results;

if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach(results => {
        console.log(results.question);
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't see a "data" property within that returned object

Comment: This is not working and not seems to be an aright solution.

Comment: @jacub I have updated with `results` as initially there was no screenshot attached. `data` was a guess.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking just for your example: If you open the API Url yourself, you can see that the resulting `data` is not an `array`, but an `object` like:

```
{
    "response_code": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "category": "Entertainment: Film",
            "type": "multiple",
            "difficulty": "medium",
            "question": "Who played Batman in the 1997 film &quot;Batman and Robin&quot;?",
            "correct_answer": "George Clooney",
            "incorrect_answers": [
                "Michael Keaton",
                "Val Kilmer",
                "Christian Bale"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

That means you should use `data.results` to itterate over the data.

Comment: Where I should use `data.results`? 
```
data.forEach(data.results => {
            console.log(results.question);
        });
```
This not work

Comment: data.results.forEach(item=>{console.log(item)}) this will work fine

Answer (score 1):

The data you're getting back from the server is an object, not an array. `.forEach` is only available on arrays.

However there is an array *within* that data called "results", and the objects within that contain the "question" properties which you're interested in.

So the fix is simple, just iterate over the "results" array instead:

```
data.results.forEach(result => {
  console.log(result.question);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    // Checking if we have status 200 good to go otherwise error
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        // Looping the data
        data.forEach(results => {
            console.log(results.question);
        });
    } else {
        // Showing error for the status
        console.log("error");
    }
};
```

Since your data is not an array it cant irterate and forEach function is used to iterater over an array.
Assuming your response consists any array as

```
 responseData: {
                sc: "0000|Success",
                 clientId: "ptm",
                  reportStatus:[
                      {reportName: "sale_report", 
                          id: "275", 
                          status: "AVAILABLE"},
                          {reportName: "sale_report", 
                          id: "276", 
                          status: "PENDING"}]
}
```

responseData.reportStatus fetch the value and then iterate over it.

```
responseData.reportStatus.forEach((item,index,arr)=>{
  console.log(item);
})
```

this will fetch you with all the items inside array.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the code actually you are looping on wrong property you should loop on the results.

```
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Opening a GET request to the API
    request.open("GET", "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10");
    // Load the request
    request.onload = function() {
      // Accessing the JSON data
      var response = JSON.parse(this.response);

      // Checking if we have status 200 good to go otherwise error
      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        // Looping the data
        var data = response.results;
        data.forEach(results => {
          console.log(results.question);
        });
      } else {
        // Showing error for the status
        console.log("error");
      }
    };
    // Request send
    request.send();
```

Working code is at below
 **https://codesandbox.io/s/white-breeze-8w8jy**

Answer (score 1):

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("GET", "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10");

   request.onload = function() {  
   var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
   if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.results.forEach(results1 => {
        console.log(results1.question);
    });
   } else {        
    console.log("error");
  }
  };

 request.send();
```

I have tried your code and you are missing results between data and forEach.
After that it is logging question in console.